# How to write JQL to find last assignee of a issue was in a specific user role of specific project?

Tags: jira, jql

I want to filter out ticket list which matches below criteria,

1. tickets assignee changed within last 5 days.
2. tickets in project "LCH" and
3. assignee was in "client" role.

currently i have below query which is by the way not working.

```
assignee was in usersInRole("LCH", "Client") and assignee changed AFTER startOfDay(-5d)
```

Comment: Where is your code and what have you tried?

Comment: `assignee was in usersInRole("LCH", "Client") and assignee changed AFTER startOfDay(-5d)` I have this JQL but it is not working. I need an alternative JQL to filterout same thing.